# What's a pythonic way to check membership in a list that could be None?

Tags: python

I need to get all keys in a dictionary whose corresponding value is above a minimum and that are in a given list. Something like:

```
result = [k for k in my_dict if my_dict[k] > min_value and k in allowed_keys]
```

However, it may be the case that I have no restriction on allowed keys. I find that the most pythonic to do it is to set allowed_keys to None. But this would leave me with the ugly piece of code:

```
if allowed_keys is None:
    result = [k for k in my_dict if my_dict[k] > min_value]
else:
    result = [k for k in my_dict if my_dict[k] > min_value and k in allowed_keys]
```

I feel like there must be a more sensible and pythonic solution. I thought of using a lambda function, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: readability is better than pythonic, half of the time.

Comment: AFAIK, being pythonic is directly related to being readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also follow good design principles (e.g. [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)) in addition to seeking the 'most pythonic' syntax for the solution.

Your code would be much clearer with the introduction of an `allow_all_keys` boolean property rather than overloading the meaning of `allowed_keys`. Doing this, the code then becomes:

```
result = [k for k in my_dict if my_dict[k] > min_value and 
                                (allow_all_keys or k in allowed_keys)]
```

From [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.
>   Simple is better than complex.
>   Readability counts

Answer (score 4):

You can check for `allowed_keys is None` within the list comprehension:

```
result = [k for k in my_dict if my_dict[k] > min_value and (allowed_keys is None or k in allowed_keys)]
```

This looks like a really strange English sentence.

Comment: +1 -- but I feel that `(allowed_keys is None or k in allowed_keys)` might be better in this case.

Comment: @senderle I love it, could I append it in my answer for compare-ration?

Comment: @senderle: Thanks for the tip. I don't know why I chose to do it in a convoluted way...

Comment: @okm, of course -- all user-contributed content is licensed under the [creative commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) license.

Answer (score 4):

Use `iteritems()` when you need to access both key and value

```
result = [k for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()
          if v > min_value
          and (k in allowed_keys if allowed_keys is not None else True)]

# shorter but seems harder to read
result = [k for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()
          if v > min_value
          and (True if allowed_keys is None else k in allowed_keys)]

# shorter but a bit weird and slower
result = [k for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()
          if v > min_value
          and (k in (allowed_keys or my_dict))]

# senderie's comment, very clear in logic, no more no less. I'd like to pick it.
result = [k for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()
          if v > min_value
          and (allowed_keys is None or k in allowed_keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your current solution works fine. It's readable, explicit and efficient(only test `allowed_keys` once when there's no restrictions).

If you really want to use a one-liner, you should set `allowed_keys` to the full set of keys when you have no restrictions.
Setting `allowed_keys` to `None` kind of means no key is allowed and that's semantically counter-intuitive..